# Drupal displaying "region" instead of content everywhere?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-modules

My completely finished website started displaying "region" in all the regions instead of the content. This was shortly after I enabled "Calendar Multiday" so perhaps it was related (although I have now disabled that module). Calendar and Date were previously enabled and working perfectly. I am not actually sure if the problem has anything to do with the module.

Anyone seen anything like this? Could it have to do with access control? I disabled the module but that didn't do anything..

To be clear, even admins cannot see the content and simply see "region" in every region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the region.tpl.php file if you have this problem as it was overriding all my content!

Answer (score 0):

please clear the cache and tell me if its solved the problem... you can clear the cache by flushing the database tables that start with cache_... , or by implementing `cache_clear_all()`, `drupal_flush_all_caches()` functions ...

Comment: Looks like the problem was a corrupted region.tpl.php in the theme. Thanks for the suggestion though! I wasn't using any caches which was part of my confusion as the site was working when I walked away but not later.